# Twitter JS/Jquery login is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Various threads says that it has been deprecated and can be done by server side scripts only. Due to tocken security purpose.

But I found those threads older, Dont know what is current scenario. Is there any way to create twitter login page using pure JS/jquery?